# Is $f(x) = 2x - 1$ a function from $\{0, 1\}$ to $\{-1, 1\}$?

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = 2x - 1$. Is f a function from $\{0,1\}$ to $\{-1,1\}$? 
I know how to determine if it's a function. I'm having a hard time understanding the bolded and italicized portion of the question. Could someone explain to me what it means?

Comment: What is $f(0)$? What is $f(1)$?

Comment: I think you mean for $\{ 0,1\}$ to be $(0,1)$ and likewise for $\{ -1,1\}$?

Comment: I don't think so, @JustinBenfield. They are sets in list form, in which case curly braces are used. Parantheses around tuples usually indicates a point in 2D space.

Comment: Please use a title that is explicit. All 500,000 questions on this site are asking for an explanation of something.

Comment: @Alec You may be right, now that I think about it.

Comment: @Alec He means intervals.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD - Not necessarily. If we let 0 and 1 be the only values in the domain, then {-1, 1} as range follows.

Comment: @Alec I meant Justin, not the op :-P. The same follows if $(0,1)$ is the domain, though. Anyway, I think you're right.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD - Oh I see. Then I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bold/italicized part indicates that $f(0) = -1$ and $f(1) = 1$.

$\{0,1\}$ is the domain of the function. I.e. values $x$ can have.

$\{-1, 1\}$ is the codomain of the function. I.e. values $f(x)$ can have.

Comment: $\{ -1,1\}$ is the codomain of the function. The range may or may not be all of the codomain.

Comment: @JustinBenfield - You're right, of course. Edited :)